# Hartshorne Lemma I.6.5; Why is $\mathfrak{m}_R\cap B\neq 0$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I've been going back through some theorems in Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry, trying to really understand the details.

I'm looking at Lemma I.6.5, which states (for those who don't have the book):

> Let $K$ be a finitely generated field extension of transcendence degree one over $k$ ($k$ algebraically closed), and let $x \in K$. Then the set of discrete valuation rings of $K/k$ not containing $x$ is finite.

I'm following Hartshorne's proof, and I'm at the point where $y\in K$ is transcendental over $k$, and $B$, defined to be the integral closure of $k[y]$ in $K$, is a Dedekind domain and finitely generated as a $k$-algebra.

He then supposes that $k[y]$ is contained in a DVR $R$ of $K/k$, which forces $B\subseteq R$ since $R$ is integrally closed in $K$. The next step is where I'm stuck:

> If $\mathfrak{m}_R$ is the maximal ideal of $R$ then $\mathfrak{n}:=B\cap\mathfrak{m}_R$ is a maximal ideal of $B$.

Part of this is obvious: that is that $\mathfrak{n}$ is a prime ideal of $B$. As $B$ is a Dedekind domain, it suffices to show that $\mathfrak{n}$ is nonzero. I feel like there must be an obvious reason why this is the case, but I'm completely drawing a blank. I'd greatly appreciate it if someone could help me out here.

Comment: I didn't think about this carefully, but is $R$ an integral ring extension of $B$? If so, then you can use the going up theorem. If $\frak{m}_R$ contracts to the zero ideal, then take a maximal ideal of $B$, it contains $(0)$ and hence there is some prime ideal in $R$ containing $\frak{m}_R$ contracting to it contradicting maximality.

Comment: @Matt, $R$ can't be an integral extension of $B$, can it? $B$, being the integral closure of $k[y]$ in $K$, is itself integrally closed in $K$.

Comment: Ah, yes. I didn't really read through the whole thing, but just look at the end for the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the pullback of $m_R$ is $(0)$, then $K = Frac(B) = B_{(0)} \subset R \subset K$, forcing $R = K$, which is absurd.

Comment: Ah, yes; everything in $B\setminus \mathfrak{n}$ is already a unit in $R$, and so $B_\mathfrak{n}\subseteq R$. I had actually already made the observation that $\mathfrak{n}=(0)$ implies every element in $B$ becomes a unit in $R$ but completely missed the fact that that forces $K\subseteq R$. Thanks!

Comment: Why the quotient field of B has to be K? This is obvious if we have already proved $B_n$ equals $R$.

Comment: @XiaoboZhuang See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/385384/fraction-field-of-the-integral-closure.