# If $B$ is an integrally closed domain and $B \to A$ is an integral extension, then $A$ is the integral closure of $B$ in $K(A)$ or not?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Here $K(A)$ and $K(B)$ mean the fraction fields of $A$ and $B$, respectively. I see that the integral closure of $B$ in $K(A)$, denoting it as $C$, satisfies $A \subseteq C$ for $B\to A$ being an integral extension. Is it true that $C = A$?

I want to show that if $p/q \in K(A)$ satisfies some monic polynomial $x^n + b_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \cdots + b_1 x + b_0 = 0$  with $b_i \in B$ and $p, q \in A$, $q$ not a unit, then $p \in (q)$. But I stucked at this point. I think if it's true, $B$ being integrally closed has to be used. Otherwise taking $A = B = k[t^2, t^3]$ is an counterexample. Or is it generally only $A \subset C$?

Some kind of an reverse of the current question may be related: [fraction field of the integral closure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/385384/fraction-field-of-the-integral-closure)

Thanks a lot for your helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The claim is not true. Choose $A=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$ and $B=\mathbb{Z}$. $B$ is integrally closed, and the extension $B \subseteq A$ is finite, hence integral. However, in this case
$$C=\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right],$$
so $A \subset C$.

On the other hand, the claim is true if $A$ is integrally closed. Indeed, denote by $D$ the integral closure of $A$ in $K(A)$. Then $A \subseteq C \subseteq D$. $A$ being integrally closed means $D=A$, so in that case $A=C=D$.

As you see, the hypothesis of $B$ being integrally closed and the extension $B \subseteq A$ being finite do not play any role.

Comment: It's a very nice counterexample and answer. Thank you very much Don.

Comment: @onriv You're welcome :)